# PHP <select> is not populating results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a php to fetch from a mysql dba and use the result set in a dropdown list as a input for another php to query on the variable.  Ideally I only want to show the lastname, firstname, and Call Sign while using the MembersId as the argument for the form php.

I get a drop down list to show but it has no data.   When I look at the source I see that the query ran and can see the result set.

I appreciate any advice I can get.

```
<html>

<?php

include('connectDb.php');

$sql="Select MembersId, lastName, firstName, callSign from 
SVARC.members";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$users = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>

<form action="LastMeetingAttendancebyDate.php" method="post">
<select name ="user">

    <?php
        foreach($users as $user){
            echo("<option value='");
            echo($user['MembersId']+"'>");
            echo($user['lastName']);
            echo",";
            echo($user['firstName']);
            echo" ";
            echo($user['callSign']);
            echo("'</option>");
        }
    ?>
 </select>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
echo($user['MembersId']+"'>");
```

you're attempting to concatenate using `+`. The concatenation operator in PHP is [`.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

However, I would suggest rewriting your block of code like this:

```
<select name="user">
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?> 
    <option value="<?= $user['MembersId'] ?>">
        <?= $user['lastName'] ?>, <?= $user['firstName'] ?> <?= $user['callSign'] ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

This makes use of PHP's [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) which is particularly nice for outputting things like HTML.

I would also recommend using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) on the values to [avoid potential XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php). Didn't add them to the sample to keep it simple, but you should look into it at the very least.